# modeling database for the same product from different venders

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql, schema, e-commerce

How does an online marketplace persist the same products being sold by multiple vendors? do they persist each vender product as a new entry or use the first entry as a reference for subsequent products?

Comment: It is mostly dependent upon the use case. You store the data to be used (CRUD operations) by the application, in an optimal way. Your data modeling process should explain what is the correct way. Also, see [Data Model Design](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.